# Setting the DataContext to the current code-behind object in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set the DataContext for my UserControl to the code-behind class of the UserControl. It's really easy to do from the code-behind side:

```
public partial class OHMDataPage : UserControl
{
    public StringList Stuff { get; set; }

    public OHMDataPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="LCDHardwareMonitor.Pages.OHMDataPage">

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

But how can I do this purely from the XAML side and at the UserControl level? It works on child nodes if I do this (and remove `DataContext = this;` from the code-behind):

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="LCDHardwareMonitor.Pages.OHMDataPage">

    <ScrollViewer
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

I'd really like to understand how to do this on the UserControl itself. I expected this to work:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="LCDHardwareMonitor.Pages.OHMDataPage"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

but it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, it seems `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"` works if on my MainWindow, but not on this UserControl. That's odd...

Comment: What's the point of a ListBox inside a ScrollViewer?

Comment: Just learning the ropes. Using placeholder stuff mostly. I see a HandlesScrolling property on ListBox. I'm guessing you ask because  ListBox already implements scrolling?

Comment: Exactly, be careful when placing one scroll component inside another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Should work.

But if your properties are not set before `InitializeComponent()` is called, the WPF binding mechanism doesn't know that your property's values are changed.

To give you a quick idea:

```
// the binding should work
public StringList Stuff { get; set; }
public Constructor()
{
    Stuff = new StringList { "blah", "blah", "foo", "bar" };
    InitializeComponent();
}

// the binding won't work
public StringList Stuff { get; set; }
public Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Stuff = new StringList { "blah", "blah", "foo", "bar" };
}
```

If you're using a list of strings, consider using an `ObservableCollection` instead. This will notify the WPF binding mechanism when items are added or removed.

Comment: Of course it's that simple...*head slap*. Thanks. The string list is just for testing purposes while I learn the ropes. Next step is a custom tree structure then implementing INotifyCollectionChanged.